# calculating memory used by "ext4_inode_cache" from /proc/slabinfo?

Tags: linux, debian, operating-systems, c, virtual-memory

On Linux I have two ways to get the memory used by `ext4_inode_cache`. First is using the `slabtop` command which gives me "CACHE SIZE" information too:

```
#  slabtop -o -s c | grep -E '(ext4_inode_cache|NAME)'
  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
118794 114631  96%    1.16K   9138       13    146208K ext4_inode_cache
```

Second is reading `/proc/slabinfo` but it doesn't give me the calculated "CACHE SIZE":

```
# grep -E '(pagesperslab|ext4_inode_cache)' /proc/slabinfo 
# name            <active_objs> <num_objs> <objsize> <objperslab> <pagesperslab> : tunables <limit> <batchcount> <sharedfactor> : slabdata <active_slabs> <num_slabs> <sharedavail>
ext4_inode_cache  114631 118794   1184   13    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata   9138   9138      0
```

How do I do calculate it from above numbers? slaptop's source code has some formula:

https://github.com/thlorenz/procps/blob/b713185dc7b4c82d8cbc9f4be7e345f09df365bb/deps/procps/proc/slab.c#L179

But I am surely doing something wrong as the result I get after my calculation doesn't match slaptop's "CACHE SIZE" output.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I figured it out:

```
"CACHE SIZE" = <pagesperslab> * <batchcount> * PAGE_SIZE
```

PAGE_SIZE is generally 4k